# Update data depending on another data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have Vue Component with N + 2 fields.
Basically user selects N tree categories (nested tree) until latest level, then select another field called type. All data comes from API.

Depending on last selected category and type I have to load data into 3rd field.
What's the best way to do it like that? So far I've tried watch, on change event and computed.

1. Computed cannot be used because loading data for 3rd field have side-effects (show loading indicator, etc).
2. On Change: Works great, but only works when user interacts (when I change data programatically, I have to manually load data
3. Watch: Almost working. I have weird bug. `category[category.length - 1]` returns undefined.

Comment: Based on the description, `watch` seems the most appropriate. You probably just need to add some guards to prevent the error.

Comment: Actually no. I don't know what's the reason. This is the result from 
`console.log(this.form.category.length);`
`console.log(this.form.category);`
inside method called from both watchers.

https://i.imgur.com/zzogHGi.png

Comment: Can you share the code for clarification like the code written inside `watch`

Comment: I refactored it a lot and now it's fine. I guess I have typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I did it with watchers.
2 watchers that call same method that loads 3rd field.